# Run certain script periodically at boot time

Tags: cron

Suppose the computer is being launched irregularly. And I want to run a certain script at boot time once in a month. But I can't setup a cron job as I don't know whether the machine will be booted at this date.

I though about this approach.

- I create a file with last date time of script execution.
- Every boot I do the following:

---

```
if(file_exists("last_boot.txt"))
{
    if(<<more then a month has passed since last date time>>)
    {
        <<run script>>
    }
}
else
{
    <<run script>>
}

<<write current date time into the file>>
```

Is is possible to do it using some standard tools without the trick with file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just* run it at either schedule using cron and check the *other* part of the schedule in the script:

One way:

```
@reboot /path/to/my_script.sh

if has_run_this_month() {
    exit
}
```

Other way:

```
0 0 1 * * /path/to/my_script.sh

if has_run_since_reboot() {
    exit
}
```

* There are several issues with this way of running things:

- Do you ever keep a machine running for more than a month? Two months? What happens in either case?
- Do you ever leave the machine *off* for more than a month? You can see where this is going…
- How do you make sure the path where you persist the state (because you *have* to store it somewhere persistent) doesn't get wiped out at boot because it's a RAM disk?

Comment: So, you add the job into cron file. At midnight every 1-st day of the month the script must be run. What is "has_run_since_reboot()"? Where to add this?

Comment: "How do you make sure the path where you persist the state" - I wanted to save the file into /root/file.txt

Comment: "Do you ever keep a machine running for more than a month?" - no. So, I think, I can just start the script every boot.

Comment: You'll need to implement `has_run_since_reboot`. You could for example save a file to a RAM disk so that it will be wiped on boot, or you could update the modified timestamp on a file, and check whether the timestamp is after the last startup time.

Comment: If I write `0 0 1 * * /path/to/my_script.sh` in cron will it run during the next boot if the machine was off at 0:0 1-st day of the month?

Comment: No, you'll have to use the other method in that case.